# How to get the correct data for paid orders in device breakdown in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

Good afternoon. Please tell me how to transfer via the measurement protocol user agent so that payments are correctly distributed across device types, platforms and browsers? Now in payment data we transmit user id, client id and session id, user-agent, sec-ch-ua, sec-ch-ua-mobile, sec-ch-ua-platform
But all payments go to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this issue for a long time, and the only solution that I have found so far (although it's not the ideal way) is to use the user_PSEUDO_ID. Since this ID is specific to each browser on each device, I am able to determine the device types, platforms, and browsers using other events with identical user_pseudo_id. To get around this, I wrote a custom query in BigQuery that creates a table for every purchase and extract user_pseudo_id from that, then checks this id in other events that contains device information. I then use this table to analyze the data.